# How can I solve Error: object 'opencpu' not found

Tags: r, opencpu

I tried to load the appdemo into opencpu and it gave me an error. How should I solve this error?

Steps to Reproduce:

```
 1. git clone git clone https://github.com/rwebapps/appdemo.git
 2. sudo -i R[enter image description here][1]
 3. library(opencpu)
 4. opencpu$browse("/library/appdemo/www")
```

[picture of the error on my terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bcW7d.png)

Answer (score 1):

In OpenCPU 2.0 you need a different command to start the server:

```
ocpu_start_server()
```

Or to directly start the `appdemo` app

```
ocpu_start_app("rwebapps/appdemo")
```

Comment: So after starting the server, how do I load the app demo because I tried install.packages("appdemo") and it did not work...

Comment: You need: `devtools::install_github("rwebapps/appdemo")`. Or you can run everything at once via: `opencpu::ocpu_start_app("rwebapps/appdemo")`

Comment: `DONE (appdemo)
[2017-07-06 11:35:00] OpenCPU single-user server, version 2.0.3
[2017-07-06 11:35:00] READY to serve at: http://localhost:5656/ocpu
[2017-07-06 11:35:00] Press ESC or CTRL+C to quit!
[2017-07-06 11:35:00] Opening http://localhost:5656/ocpu/apps/rwebapps/appdemo
[2017-07-06 11:35:01] GET /ocpu/apps/rwebapps/appdemo
**ERROR: [on_request_read] connection reset by peer
[2017-07-06 11:35:01] GET /ocpu/apps/rwebapps/appdemo/
ERROR: [on_request_read] connection reset by peer**
[2017-07-06 11:35:01] GET /ocpu/apps/rwebapps/appdemo/www/`

Comment: @swirlydino which OS is this? If it doesn't work can you open an issue on github with your sessionInfo() and everything?

Comment: this is Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS. and ok ill do that :)